# Lightning protection for Antenna Connector

Tags: pcb, antenna, esd, lighting, shield

I want to add lightning and ESD protection for the antenna used with my PCB (Wireless Gateway). The antennas that will be used with my PCB are [Pole Mount Antenna](http://parsec-t.com/products/pole-mount-lora-antenna/). There are three different types of Antennas needed with my PCB: 4G LTE, GPS and LoRa Antennas. Currently, I am using [SMA PCB Connector](https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/taoglas-limited/PCB.SMAFRA.HT/931-1361-ND/5034736). I want to know how to connect shielding of these connectors. Should I connect it to the enclosure's shield or to the ground (for RF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESD protection should not be needed as the receiver/transceiver modules should already have build-in ESD protection. Any ESD protection you add will influence the matching between Antenna and Module resulting in reduced sensitivity and/or transmitted output power. It is a much better approach to just make sure that the metal parts of the antennas cannot be touched, for example by using an antenna that sits inside a plastic housing. Then you don't need extra ESD protection and you can rely on the module's build in protection.

Lightning protection:

All you can do here is make sure that the mast / pole you're using is conductive and well earthed. Then also make sure the mast/pole is the highest point.

But even then, if lightning strikes the mast / pole directly it is simply a matter of **luck** if your receiver modules will survive or not. A lightning strike can be so powerful that it can rip out the mains wiring from a wall. There is simply **no way** that you can reliably protect sensitive low power electronics from that.

I would **not** connect the shielding of the connectors to the metal case. I would only connect the metal of the case to the **supply ground**. Connecting the RF side can interfere with the reception as it is a sensitive point so I would not do that.